Discord bot is connecting to the voice channel but not playing the music with YouTube URL
I am making a discord bot and trying to add some music related commands to my bot. The Main issue is that the bot is connecting to the voice channel where the user is but not playing the music from youtube link. See this is code I wrote so far.
#MODULES----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
import asyncio
import discord
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands

#MAIN-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
class MusicCommands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False

        self.music_queue = []
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio/best', 'verbose': True}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'options': '-vn'}
        
        self.vc = None
        self.ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS)

    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        if self.music_queue:
            self.is_playing = True
            url = self.music_queue.pop(0)
            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after = lambda e: self.play_next(ctx))

    async def play_next(self, ctx):
        if self.music_queue:
            url = self.music_queue.pop(0)
            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after = lambda e: self.play_next(ctx))

        else:
            self.is_playing = False
            asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.vc.disconnect(), self.client.loop)

    # (1) Play command.
    @commands.command(
        name = 'play',
        aliases = ['Play', 'PLAY'],
        description = 'Plays a song in the voice channel the user is currently in.'
    )
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url = None):
        try:
            if not ctx.author.voice:
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title = '__Error__',
                    description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, You are not connected to a voice channel.',
                    color = discord.Color.red()
                )
                await ctx.reply(embed = embed)
                return
            
            if not url:
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title = '__Error__',
                    description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, Please provide a valid YouTube URL.',
                    color = discord.Color.red()
                )
                await ctx.reply(embed = embed)
                return
            
            channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            if self.vc is None or not self.vc.is_connected():
                self.vc = await channel.connect()

            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(channel)

            song_info = self.ytdl.extract_info(url, download = False)
            song_url = song_info['formats'][0]['url']
            song_title = song_info['title']
            self.music_queue.append(song_url)

            if not self.is_playing:
                await self.play_music(ctx)

            embed = discord.Embed(
                title = '__Music__',
                description = f'''
                 Playing Music...

                 Playing: {song_title}
                 Requested By: {ctx.author.mention}
                ''',
                color = discord.Color.dark_orange()
            )
            await ctx.reply(embed = embed)
        
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'An error occurred in play command: {e}')

#FUCNTION TO ADD COG TO THE BOT-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(MusicCommands(client))


And this is the error I am getting when I type !play <url> in the server's channel.
[debug] Encodings: locale cp1252, fs utf-8, out utf-8, pref cp1252
[debug] youtube-dl version 2021.12.17
[debug] Python version 3.12.1 (CPython) - Windows-11-10.0.22631-SP0
[debug] exe versions: ffmpeg N-55702-g920046a, ffprobe N-55702-g920046a
[debug] Proxy map: {}
2024-04-05 17:36:46 INFO     discord.voice_client Connecting to voice...
2024-04-05 17:36:46 INFO     discord.voice_client Starting voice handshake... (connection attempt 1)
2024-04-05 17:36:46 INFO     discord.voice_client Voice handshake complete. Endpoint found india9259.discord.media
[youtube] q4_aISHkMPg: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xesch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 815, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xesch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 836, in __extract_info
    ie_result = ie.extract(url)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xesch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 534, in extract
    ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xesch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\youtube.py", line 1794, in _real_extract
    'uploader_id': self._search_regex(r'/(?:channel|user)/([^/?&#]+)', owner_profile_url, 'uploader id') if owner_profile_url else None,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xesch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 1012, in _search_regex
    raise RegexNotFoundError('Unable to extract %s' % _name)
youtube_dl.utils.RegexNotFoundError: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

An error occurred in play command: ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

As the error says add --verbose flag for detailed info.
I used it here self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio/best', 'verbose': True} but it is not helping that much.
Also I found a pretty similar question as well, he said something to add ffmpeg path in self.voice.play for me it is self.vc.play but it is also not working.
Please help me to fix this issue.

Does this answer your question?

Thanks buddy it will help alot. I will try it later.

Yes it did. I used yt-dlp library instead as you mentioned in that post. And after making some helper functions and more commands the bot is working as I expected. Thank you.
